# C program eating all my RAM+SWAP resources

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

i made simple program to find out md5 checksum of user input (input[1;6])
Problem is that these for loops seems to eat all my RAM + Swap resources which leads to pc hang. What i am doing wrong ? What's the better way to manage system memory ?

```
/* 

C Example w/o mpi 

mpicc md5.c -o md5 -lcrypto -lssl
./md5

Single process on c2d laptop
String finding matchin md5 of string "hello" tooks  

*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#  define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#  include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#  define SHA1 CC_SHA1
#else
#  include <openssl/md5.h>
#endif


char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    #ifdef COUNT // Very bad name, not long enough, too general, etc..
    static int const count = COUNT;
    #else
    static int const count = 6; // default value
    #endif
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    begin = clock();

    int bflag = 0;
    int sflag = 0;
    int index;
    int c;
    char input[count];
    char action[2]; // char + \n
    char *inputResult = (char*)malloc(33);
    char *tmpResult = (char*)malloc(33);
    char inputGuess[6];
    int i,j,k,l,m,n;
    char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    printf("Please enter string to guess (max 6 char - latin letters and numbers): ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    inputResult = str2md5(input, strlen(input));
    printf("Md5 to find = %s \n", inputResult);
    printf("Continue? (Y/n) ");
    scanf("%s", action);
    if(action == "n\n"){
        return 0;
    }


    /* for 1 char input */
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(letters); i++){ //letters + numbers
        char guess1[] = {letters[i], '\0'};
/*      printf("%s\n", guess1);*/
        if(strcmp(str2md5(guess1, strlen(guess1)),inputResult) == 0){       
            printf("We guessed it! Your input was - %s \n", guess1);
            end = clock();
            time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent);
            free(inputResult);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /* for 2 char input */
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(letters); i++){ //letters + numbers
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(letters); j++){
            char guess2[] = {letters[i], letters[j], '\0'};
            if(strcmp(str2md5(guess2, strlen(guess2)),inputResult) == 0){       
                printf("We guessed it! Your input was - %s \n", guess2);
                end = clock();
                time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                printf("Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent);
                free(inputResult);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /* for 3 char input */
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(letters); i++){ //letters + numbers
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(letters); j++){
            for(k=0; k<sizeof(letters); k++){
                char guess3[] = {letters[i], letters[j], letters[k], '\0'};
/*              printf("%s\n", guess3);*/
                if(strcmp(str2md5(guess3, strlen(guess3)),inputResult) == 0){       
                    printf("We guessed it! Your input was - %s \n", guess3);
                    end = clock();
                    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                    printf("Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent);
                    free(inputResult);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* for 4 char input */
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(letters); i++){ //letters + numbers
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(letters); j++){
            for(k=0; k<sizeof(letters); k++){
                for(m=0; m<sizeof(letters); m++){
                    char guess4[] = {letters[i], letters[j], letters[k], letters[m], '\0'};
/*                  printf("%s\n", guess4);*/
                    if(strcmp(str2md5(guess4, strlen(guess4)),inputResult) == 0){       
                        printf("We guessed it! Your input was - %s \n", guess4);
                        end = clock();
                        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                        printf("Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent);
                        free(inputResult);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* for 5 char input */
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(letters); i++){ //letters + numbers
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(letters); j++){
            for(k=0; k<sizeof(letters); k++){
                for(m=0; m<sizeof(letters); m++){
                    for(n=0; n<sizeof(letters); n++){
                        char guess5[] = {letters[i], letters[j], letters[k], letters[m], letters[n], '\0'};
/*                      printf("%s\n", guess5);*/
                        if(strcmp(str2md5(guess5, strlen(guess5)),inputResult) == 0){       
                            printf("We guessed it! Your input was - %s \n", guess5);
                            end = clock();
                            time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                            printf("Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent);
                            free(inputResult);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* for 6 char input */
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(letters); i++){ //letters + numbers
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(letters); j++){
            for(k=0; k<sizeof(letters); k++){
                for(m=0; m<sizeof(letters); m++){
                    for(n=0; n<sizeof(letters); n++){
                        for(l=0; l<sizeof(letters); l++){
                            char guess6[] = {letters[i], letters[j], letters[k], letters[m], letters[n], letters[l], '\0'};
/*                          printf("%s\n", guess6);*/
                            if(strcmp(str2md5(guess6, strlen(guess6)),inputResult) == 0){       
                                printf("We guessed it! Your input was - %s \n", guess6);
                                end = clock();
                                time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                                printf("Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent);
                                free(inputResult);
                                return 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nobody is going to debug all this code for you.  You obviously have a infinite loop or many memory allocations that are not being freed.  Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Holy mother of nesting!!! Some parts of code is looks like [Eiffel Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower). o____O

Comment: most people precompute a table of hashes and then load it

Comment: If you're experiencing unbounded memory growth, that strongly implies that you have a memory leak... you're probably not freeing everything you allocated.

Comment: Just have at most three `for` loops then use a function. Makes things more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without checking the whole code: You have at least one `malloc` without corresponding `free`.

`str2md5` allocates 33 bytes for `out` which is returned. There are several lines of the form `strcmp(str2md5(guess3, strlen(guess3)),inputResult)` in which the pointer resulting from the `malloc` for `out` is temporary, lost and can therefore never be freed again.

Considering you call these lines in multiple nested loops, this is likely causing your issue.

This problem is avoided by assigning the result of `str2md5` to a local pointer and freeing it after executing `strcmp`. Here an example for the line mentioned earlier:

```
char* str2md5_ret = str2md5(guess3, strlen(guess3));
int cmp = strcmp(str2md5_ret, inputResult);
free(str2md5_ret);
if(cmp == 0)
  //...
```

Having another look over the code I notice several other problems:

You allocate for `inputResult` right at declaration, but then you assign a new data block from `str2md5` to it. So there are again 33 bytes leaked. Then you allocate for `tmpResult` which is not freed and actually never even used again. This is again 33 bytes leaked. `inputResult` is not freed if none of the loops break.

As others pointed out the deeply nested loops are bad style. You can actually write all of them in a single recursive function with a single loop. That might be more readable, debug-able, maintainable and flexible.

You also can get rid of nearly all `malloc`'s by retaining one `char*` with 33 bytes length for the output of all `str2md5` calls and passing it as parameter instead of returning it.

Comment: 'multiple nested loops' - understatement of the year :)

Comment: +1 For quickly pointing out the issue. Based on my calculation, allocating 33 bytes for a 62 iteration on single char, 62*62 on a double char, 62*62*62 on triple char up to 62*62*62*62*62*62 on a six char, the result is 1.73 TB. Can you edit your post and suggest that he assign the allocated memory to a pointer so he can free it after each compare?

Comment: @Nabla many thanks for your solution! it's my hello world program in C and you were able to eliminate memory leaks in it.

Comment: Are the nested loops actually hindering readability here? It's pretty obvious what they do. Edit: A lot more obvious than a recursive function would be. But the recursive function way would be more flexible (e.g. you could input the number of characters at runtime)

Comment: @immibis Yes, a recursive function might be less readable, although I do not think that simple recursive function are in general less readable. But I think the current loops should at least be condensed a bit, for example by putting the most inner block (which is always basically the same) into a function. In the current situation I wouldn't notice an error in one of the loops.

Comment: "In the current situation I wouldn't notice an error in one of the loops" - that is true. The current version is great for writing once. Your version might be more maintainable, at the cost of being harder to skim and harder to write the first time.